# How to generate translations files with grunt angular-translate from default json files with translations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, gruntjs, angular-translate

I have an angular app that needs to have multiple language translations. I have setup angular translate task as follows. What I want to create is a different language file which I load later using useStaticFilesLoader;

```
i18nextract: {
          default_options: {
            jsonSrc:  ['<%= srcdir %>/i18n/*.json'],
            src: [ '<%= src.js %>', '<%= src.html %>'],
            lang:     ['ro', 'en', 'fr', 'pl', 'de'],
            dest:     '<%= distdir %>/i18n'
          }
        }
```

In srcdir there are multiple language files with original translations, to use them as a source:
Unfortunately, the result doesn't load the translation

Also tried passing `source: ['<%= srcdir %>/i18n/*.json']`, and `jsonSrc: {"ro":'<%= srcdir %>/i18n/ro.json', "de":'<%= srcdir %>/i18n/de.json'}`, without any luck.

Another try was to have all default translations in one json file:

```
{
    "ro": { "key":"value"},
    "de": { "key":"value"},...
}
```

But I didn't succeed.

Is there an option I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the simple  directory structure as follows, then this should work

myproject
     --> Src/index.html and src/js files
     --> Gruntfile.js
     --> package.json

I have uploaded a sample in the github, that might be useful for you.

https://github.com/anilkris/Grunti18nExtraction

Regards,